# Creating a has_one type relationship in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I'm receiving JSON from the server that looks something like:

```
{
  data: [
    {
      foo: "hello",
      bar_id: "92934848202"
    },
    {
      foo: "hello again",
      bar_id: "39393020201"
    },
  ]
}
```

I'm reading it into an observableArray called self.data using the mapping plugin like:

```
self.data(ko.mapping.fromJS(json).data());
```

I have another module called bar, that reads in all of bars from the server along with their ids.  I have a method in bar that is able to return an object with a method called find.  So

```
bar.find("39393020201") // returns object
```

But what I'd really like to do is have the the self.data observableArray be able to directly access bar, by doing something like:

```
self.data()[0].bar // ideally returns object?
```

The closest I've been able to get so far is to add a custom function like this:

```
ko.observable.fn.bar = function() {
  return bar.find(this());
};
```

But this requries that I call

```
self.data()[0].bar_id.bar
```

which is not very pretty.  But any function I add to observableArray operates on the entire array and not a specific object in that array.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to break down the mapping process and manually add an observable "bar" - the mapping plugin allows to replace the bar_id (or any other) observable with a computed observable that does whatever you want it to, but you can not create a property that is not present in your data object (such as "bar").

```
var tmp = [];

for (var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
    // Map only one object in the json.data array
    var o = ko.mapping.fromJS(json.data[i]);

    // Add a computed observable that turns bar_id into bar
    o.bar = ko.computed(function() {
        return self.bar.find( o.bar_id() );
    });

    tmp.push(o);
}

self.data(tmp);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hTYy3/2/

Comment: Thanks Niko, I was hoping for a cleaner way.. maybe I'll fork knockout and see if I can build something in.